# Generate the date based on the more than 1 constraint

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 having  column for date_1 with values from 01/09/2019 to 30/09/2019. i.e. 30 values and respective count.

**DF1**

```
    date_1    count
    01/09/2019  5
    02/09/2019  4
    03/09/2019  5
    04/09/2019  6
    05/09/2019  7
    06/09/2019  8
    07/09/2019  10
    08/09/2019  9
    09/09/2019  11
    10/09/2019  12
    11/09/2019  13
    12/09/2019  14
    13/09/2019  15
    14/09/2019  16
```

I want to generate a dataframe df2 using df1 with some constraints such that :

1. There is a new column date_2.
2. date_2 are generated on the feature of the count present in df1.

For example: a new dataframe df2 will have 5 entries(since count = 5) for 01/09/2019 and date_2 column can take values from 30 days before date_1 to 30/08/2019(current date in date_1 - 1) i.e. for 01/09/2019, the values that date_2 can take is from (01/09/2019 - 30 = 01/08/2019) to (01/09/2019 - 1 = 30/08/2019).

date_2 can be randomly selected from the range (`30 - date_1` to `date_1 - 1`) i.e. in our example for 01/09/2019, from 02/08/2019 to 30/08/2019

Important point to note that the date_2 should have an increasing count in df2 as well.

**Expected Output :**

```
    date_1    count   date_2
    01/09/2019  5     02/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     10/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     12/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     25/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     28/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     03/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     10/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     20/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     25/08/2019
```

**EDIT**

I was able to generate date_2 using the function :

```
def pick_random_delta_in_range(min_days=1, max_days=30):
    if min_days is None and max_days is None:
        return datetime.timedelta(days=1, minutes=0, seconds=0)
    if min_days is None:
        return max_days
    if max_days is None:
        return min_days
    days_to_be_added = random.randint(min_days, max_days)
    return datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_be_added, minutes=0, seconds=0)

def gen_date_by_delta(src_dates, date_format, delta_min, delta_max):
    gen_dates = []
    for dt in src_dates:
        src_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, date_format)

        if src_date is None:
            gen_dates.append("")
            continue

        chosen_delta = pick_random_delta_in_range(min_days=delta_min, max_days=delta_max)

        result_date = (src_date + chosen_delta).strftime(date_format)
        gen_dates.append(result_date)

    return gen_dates

date_2 = gen_date_by_delta(src_dates=df1["date_1"], date_format=date_format, delta_min=1, delta_max=30)
```

***Currently the delta is generated randomly and might generate the same delta for the same date_1 resulting in the duplicate entries. I don't want to generate the duplicate entries. ***

I am also not able to understand how to replicate the fields in the dataframe according to the count and generate the dates accordingly.

Can anyone help/suggest a way to generate the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following "replication" function:

```
def repl(row):
    d1 = row.date_1
    cnt = row['count']
    dates = [ d1 - pd.Timedelta(n, 'D') for n in
            np.sort(np.random.choice(30, cnt, False))[::-1] ]
    return pd.DataFrame({'date_1': d1, 'count': cnt, 'date_2': dates})
```

Then apply it, concatenate the results and save as *DF2*:

```
DF2 = pd.concat(df.apply(repl, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Note that in the above code *row['count']* can **not** be replaced
with *row.count*, because there is a *Pandas* method of this name.
Actually this is just as example how **not** to assign column names.
You should **not** use names of existing methods.

## Edit following the comment about "all values"

To consume all dates from the range, the procedure is more complicated and
involves creation of a dedicated class to generate dates from a pool.

The date assignment algorithm is as follows:

- The dates pool is created at the start, from *min* date - 30 days to
  the *max* date.
- On each call:

  - Step 1: Get the first possible date.
  - Step 2: Get further dates from the pool.
  - On both these steps the dates assigned are deleted from the pool.
  - Step 3: If no more dates are in the pool, from the allowed range,
    but we need more, generate dates from the possible range, but without
    repeating dates selected for this row so far.

This class contains one more "trick", to compensate for the fact that the
applied function is called **twice** for the first row.
This is a piece of optimisation contained in *Pandas*, but in this case
it has a side effect (consumption of some "initial" dates, which aren't
actually included in the result), so I had to compensate for this.

Proceed as follows:

Create a pair of *Timedelta* variables used in various points:

```
td1 = pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')
td30 = pd.Timedelta(30, 'D')
```

Then define a date generator class:

```
class DateGen:
    ''' Dates generator
    d1, d2 - date range
    '''
    def __init__(self, d1, d2):
        rng = pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq='D')
        self.dates = pd.Series(rng, index=rng)
        self.firstCall = True

    def popDate(self, d1, d2):
        wrk = self.dates[self.dates.between(d1, d2)]
        siz = wrk.size
        if siz > 0:
            dat = wrk.sample().iloc[0] if siz > 1 else wrk.iloc[0]
            self.dates.pop(dat)
            return dat, True
        return None, False

    def popDates(self, d1, d2, n):
        ret = []
        if self.firstCall:
            self.firstCall = False
            return ret
        # Step 1: Get the first possible date
        dat, ok = self.popDate(d1, d1)
        if ok:
            ret.append(dat)
        # Step 2: Get further dates not consumed so far
        while len(ret) < n:
            dat, ok = self.popDate(d1, d2)
            if not ok:
                break
            ret.append(dat)
        # Step 3: Repeat dates already consumed
        while len(ret) < n:
            shft = np.random.randint(30)
            dat = d2 - pd.Timedelta(shft, 'D')
            if dat not in ret:   # Without repetitions
                ret.append(dat)
        return ret
```

Instantiate an object of this class with date range according to dates
in *DF1*:

```
dg = DateGen(DF1.date_1.min() - td30, DF1.date_1.max())
```

The replication function is this time a bit different:

```
def repl(row):
    d1 = row.date_1
    cnt = row['count']
    dates = np.sort(dg.popDates(d1 - td30, d1 - td1, cnt))
    return pd.DataFrame({'date_1': d1, 'count': cnt, 'date_2': dates})
```

It pops dates from the generator object, then sorts them and returns
in the returned DataFrame.

And the last step is to apply it:

```
DF2 = pd.concat(DF1.sort_values('date_1').\
    apply(repl, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Because the dates order is significant now, I started with sort by *date_1*.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I am getting the error `("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'Timedelta'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: I also wanted to have another constraint that all maximum values for date_2 i.e. date_2 should have all the values between min and max i.e. from 01/08/2019 to 30/09/2019 (since date_1 have range from 01/08/2019 to 31/09/2019). Can we incorporate the same as well here ?

Comment: I wrote my code assuming that *date_1* is of *datetime* type. If it is not the case, e.g. your read it as string, start from converting it.

Comment: I converted the same to datetime, can you take a look at the other comment i.e. date_2 should have all the values between min and max i.e. from 01/08/2019 to 30/09/2019 (since date_1 have range from 01/08/2019 to 31/09/2019). Can we incorporate the same as well here ?

Comment: can you please take a look at this ?

Comment: The edit is not exactly what I expected... what I meant to say that each date_2 should at least have 1 entry in the data frame. For example 02/08/2019 can only appear with 01/09/2019. The count of date_2 should remain the same. I want entries from 02/08/2019 to 30/09/2019 to be in date_2 appearing at least once

Comment: I corrected my solution. The number of rows is according to the *count*, but in total they "consume" all available dates.

Comment: Perfectly explained, Thank you so much for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. Make a function which takes a row of your dataframe as argument and the allowed dates from which pick the amount of random dates, and let it return a dataframe of the given number of rows. You can use `apply` to use this function on each row. Then you can concatenate all these dataframes.

As to not generate duplicates `'date_2'` values, use [numpy random shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html). It will randomly change the order of the elements in an array. You can then just pick the first n elements.

Here I also use [pandas date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to generate the range of dates from which pick the random dates. This is done once (it is more efficient since they are always the same), and then the dates are passed to the `makedate2` function when called by `apply`.

```
def makedate2(row, dates):
    cnt = row['count']
    np.random.shuffle(dates) #randomly change the order of dates
    return pd.DataFrame({'date_1':row['date_1'],
                         'count':cnt,
                         'date_2':dates[:cnt]}
                       )

alldates = pd.date_range(df['date_1'].min() - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='D'), df['date_1'].max() - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='D')).to_numpy()
res = df.apply(lambda x : makedate2(x, alldates), axis=1)
df2 = pd.concat(res.to_numpy()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

A possible `df2` using the sample data you provided is:

```
        date_1  count     date_2
0   2019-01-09      5 2019-09-26
1   2019-01-09      5 2019-09-11
2   2019-01-09      5 2019-05-18
3   2019-01-09      5 2019-10-15
4   2019-01-09      5 2019-06-06
..         ...    ...        ...
130 2019-09-14     16 2019-04-12
131 2019-09-14     16 2019-04-05
132 2019-09-14     16 2019-10-08
133 2019-09-14     16 2019-05-05
134 2019-09-14     16 2019-11-09
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to define 1 more constraint i.e. date_2 should have all the values between min and max i.e. from 01/08/2019 to 30/09/2019 (since date_1 have range from 01/08/2019 to 31/09/2019). Can we incorporate the same as well here ?

Comment: This additional constraint doesn't make much sense to me. If you want to pick dates from 30 days before date_1, setting a minimum value equal to the minimum date in date_1 means that the minimum date in date_1 will have no possible values for date_2

Comment: I think you misunderstood.. what I am trying to say is that date_1 has values ( 01/09/2019- 31/09/2019), date_2 should have all values between (01/08/2019-30/09/2019) for date_1 (01/09/2019), the minimum value date_2 can have is 01/08/2019 and for date_1 (31/09/2019) the date that date_2 can have maximum value is 30/09/2019. 
I want to have date_2 all the values between (01/08/2019 - 30/09/2019)

Comment: So basically you want for all the rows to pick random dates from the same interval [min(date_1) - 30days, max(date_1) - 1day]?

Comment: Exactly, this is exactly what I want

Comment: What I expect is for date_2 to have all the values available. I.e. from 02/08/2019 to 30/09/2019 all values appearing at least once in the data frame

Comment: Will the edit incorporate the last comment I.e. all dates for range of date_2 that is from 01/08/2019 to 30/09/2018. Cuz the output shows the same as earlier in your answer.

Comment: The output does not show all the 135 lines so it's hard to see in the answer, but yes, now dates are taken from that range for each line of the first dataframe.

Comment: So the thing is that 01/08/2019 only can appear with 01/09/2019 and not with others since that’s the only date_1 (01/09/2019) having range I.e. 30-date_1 and it cant be seen in the output.